# Arrange the values in a column in ascending order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have the below query where I am trying to arrange the "weekNumber" in ascending order such as week1,week2,week3,week4,... and so on

```
SELECT WeekNumber,pointsRewarded FROM chart_copy 
WHERE EmployeeID = '2164'
order by WeekNumber asc ;
```

But the problem is it is not giving me the desired output.

**What it gives is this :**

[image: img]

**Kindly help.I am using sql server -2012.**

Comment: That sort is correct - you hand it a bunch of *strings* and it sorts the strings alphabetically. If you wish to consider sorting based on *some part* of that string consisting of *digits* and you'd like those to be sorted by *numeric* sorting rules, you might want to consider not *embedding* the numbers inside a string in the first place. Why are you *storing* the redundant string `week` in your `WeekNumber` column at all? Surely that text could be rendered by your front-end application or report builder?

Comment: Since you already know that its the "week" number being stored, would suggest just storing the number as a numeric type, and removing the "week" prefix. That way, the sorting will yield the results that you need.

Comment: whatever u guys are saying is obvious.Anyways,thanks for the input.

Comment: order by convert(int,replace(weekNumebr,'week',''))

Comment: @PramodMaharjan thanks.Works perfect.